# How to read a line from python currently in console?

Tags: python, console, python-asyncio

I want to use a line of code that can read what I was typing in console, for use with `asyncio` module in python. My code prints data when it receives it from the server, and after it does that, I want it to read what I was typing and save it to a variable. I am fine with having to use a non-standard module.

Information about program:

- Currently reads stdin non-blocking using asyncio loop.run_in_executor
- Program runs using loop.create_connection, then uses loop.run_forever with the stdin reader added as a task.

Code:

```
#!python3.5
#chatroom client

import socket, sys, os, traceback, asyncio
from threading import Lock

DBG = False #More Error printing using full_error function

#async stuf
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
lock = Lock()
prev_stdin = ""

#Server Location
target = 'localhost'
port = 17532
buffer_size = 1024
server = None
transports = [] #an array of async.iotransport`s

#Functions for Error handling
full_error = lambda: traceback.print_exception(*sys.exc_info())
pause = lambda: None #make it global for below

#Pause system compatability
if os.name[0:5]=='posix':
    def pause():
        os.system('read -n1 -r -p "Press any key to continue . . ." key')
elif os.name[0:2]=='nt':
    def pause():
        os.system("pause")
else:
    def pause():
        input("Press enter to continue . . .")

def empty_stdin():
    output = ""
    while True:
        temp = sys.stdin.buffer.read(1)
        if temp == "":
            break
        else:
            output += temp
    return output

if DBG:
    loop.set_debug(DBG)

async def write():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        line = await loop.run_in_executor(None, sys.stdin.readline)
        line = prev_stdin + line
        prev_stdin = ""
        for i in transports:
            loop.call_soon(i.write,line.encode('utf-8'))

class Server(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self,transport):
        self.transport = transport
        transport.write(b"Connected")
    def data_received(self, data):
        print("\n%s"%data.decode('utf-8'))
        prev_stdin = empty_stdin()
        print(prev_stdin,)



try:
    coro = loop.create_connection(Server, host=target, port=port)
    task = loop.create_task(coro)
    print("hi")
    print(transports)
    server, serverp = loop.run_until_complete(task)
    transports += [server]
    user_input = loop.create_task(write())
    #loop.add_reader(sys.stdin, write)
    loop.run_forever()
    print('end')

except Exception as e:
    if DBG:
        full_error()
    else:
        print(type(e))
        print(e)
    pause()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: maybe showing some code would be a good idea...

Comment: We need to see your code. Gendolf is absent :( ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem (Windows only) by using `msvcrt` to catch a single character and some code changes.

New Functions/Changes

1. draw_screen:

   - clear screen using `os.system("cls")`
   - **print lines that I save when I print info (Could get laggy)**
   - print a cursor with what I am currently typing (">> Hello")
2. write:

   - **replaced sys.stdin.readline with msvcrt.getch**
   - A lot more changes
3. everywhere:

   - **Whenever I would print, instead add it to `screen` variable which is an array that holds everything. Then it calls draw_screen()**
   - removed prev_stdin stuff
   - removed some other print statements

Final Code (For now):

```
#!python3.5
#chatroom client

import sys, os, traceback, asyncio, msvcrt
from threading import Lock

DBG = False #More Error printing using full_error function

screen = [] #holds lines of text that are printed to the screen
line = ""

#async stuf
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
lock = Lock()


#Server Location
target = 'localhost'
port = 17532
buffer_size = 1024
server = None
transports = [] #an array of async.iotransport`s

#Functions for Error handling
full_error = lambda: traceback.print_exception(*sys.exc_info())

#system compatable functions
if os.name[0:5]=='posix':
    def pause():
        os.system('read -n1 -r -p "Press any key to continue . . ." key')
    def cls():
        os.system("clear")
elif os.name[0:2]=='nt':
    def pause():
        os.system("pause")
    def cls():
        os.system("cls")
else:
    def pause():
        input("Press enter to continue . . .")
    def cls():
        os.system("clear")

def draw_screen():
    cls()
    for i in screen:
        print(i)
    print("> ", line, end="\r") #Draws current line of text being typed

if DBG:
    loop.set_debug(DBG)

async def write():
    global line
    while True:
        temp = await loop.run_in_executor(None, msvcrt.getch)
        temp = temp.decode('utf-8')
        if temp == "\b":
            line = line[0:len(line)-1]
        elif not (temp == "\r" or temp == "\n"):
            line += temp
        else:
            for i in transports:
                loop.call_soon(i.write,line.encode('utf-8'))
            line = ""
        draw_screen()

class Server(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self,transport):
        self.transport = transport
        transport.write(b"Connected")
    def data_received(self, data):
        global screen
        screen += ["%s"%data.decode('utf-8')]
        draw_screen()



try:
    coro = loop.create_connection(Server, host=target, port=port)
    task = loop.create_task(coro)
    server, serverp = loop.run_until_complete(task)
    transports += [server]
    user_input = loop.create_task(write())
    loop.run_forever()
    print('end')

except Exception as e:
    if DBG:
        full_error()
    else:
        print(type(e))
        print(e)
    pause()
    sys.exit()
```